# Как добиться такого интересного эффекта?

Tags: веб-программирование

Только что набрел на сайт http://www.frondevo.com/ru/, там когда кликаешь по навигации происходит очень интересный эффект. Как добиться такого же эффекта? Flash вроде не используется, хотя могу ошибаться, так как сижу под Линуксом в старой Мозилле, у меня не показывает флэш это или нет.

Comment: навигация сделана **плохо**, т.к. не меняется url, т.о. я не могу скинуть прямую ссылку на "Меню знаний", например, а вообще, это обычная обработка кликов по меню с дельнейшей анимацией положения блока с контентом. для команды, позиционурующей себя как front-end разработчики, сделано откровенно слабо

Comment: Соглашусь. Вообще в таких случаях делают якоря, но как их привязать к JS - не знаю. Если подскажете - думаю, будет интересно.

Comment: [Routing](https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Routing)

Comment: То, что не меняется URL - это еще полбеды. Хуже то, что анимация сделана не качественно. А при zoom'е отличном от 100% все вообще начинает перекашивается и дергаться.

Comment: Согласен, у меня стоит Ubuntu 10.10 + FireFox 3.6.10 - при анимации сильно дергается, а так вообще идея очень не плохая.

Comment: и правда, не резиновая вёрстка даёт о себе знать, на больших разрешениях контент позиционируется не по центру, а по левую сторону. при маленьких - всё тоже не очень гладко

Comment: Честно говоря, *совершенно неинтересный эффект.*

Comment: видимо ТС не видел ничего подобного [Air Jordan 2012](http://www.nike.com/jumpman23/aj2012/)

- [Креативные сайты с нестандартными элементами](http://habrahabr.ru/post/140676/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabs, slider, animation. Комбинация оных даст такой эффект. Как такое сделать? - ну надо писать и все. В качестве примера брать сразу их [js файл](http://frondevo.com/js/main-2.js) и поэтапно пытаться понять что происходит...

Comment: То есть это все сделано на jQuery + добавлены самописные функции и методы!?

Comment: Да, это фактически js (на jquery) приложение, слайдер самописный, используются в основном невизуальные плагины для колеса мыши и т.д. в остальном все реализуется оригинально. То, что там не поддерживается смнена url, ну или хотя бы хэша url, недоработка конечно и стоило бы это доделать, но это по большому счету мелочи.

Comment: Обратите внимание - там параллакс эффект еще есть — объекты, которые "Ближе" к наблюдателю, быстрее проезжают, нежели средний и дальний план.

Comment: @sergiks, ага, ну поэтому слайдер и самописный. Можно было бы использовать для эффекта просто два слайдера, а вообще эффект не очень заметный....